# How to prevent users from creating new tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created the code to update the tags in the current post.

```
$tags = get_the_tags();  
if( current_user_can('author') || current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ){  
    if ($tags > 0){  

    foreach ($tags as $tag){  
        $list_tag .= "{$tag->name}, ";  
}
        $tag_edit = '
        <form method="POST">
        <textarea class="textarea_post_tag" name="post_get_tags" id="RRR">
        '.$list_tag.'
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Upgrade">
        </form>
        ';   
    echo $tag_edit  ;
}}

if ($_POST['post_get_tags']){    
    wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $_POST['post_get_tags']  );  
}
```

But I need that when editing tags

If the post does not contain the specified tags in the database,

then instead of the tag was displayed ""

Example

if the textarea was entered

tag-existing, tag-new, tag-existing,

then it would be displayed

tag-existing, tag-existing,

Answer (score 1):

With something like that you should be able to do it (code explained in the comments):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['post_get_tags'])
{
    // Split post_get_tags string into an array using the comma as delimiter.
    $tags_got_exploded = explode(',', $_POST['post_get_tags']);
    // Remove whitespaces from every value of the array (we want a clean tag name for each value of the array).
    $tags_got_exploded = array_map('trim', $tags_got_exploded);

    /*
     * Get an array with all the tags allowed to be added.
     * get_tags https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags
     * Returns a multidimensional array where the column_key "name" contains the tag name
     * Just return an array with tag names allowed
     */
    $tags_allowed = array_column(get_tags(), 'name');

    // Iterate over every tag got
    foreach ($tags_got_exploded as $key => &$tag_got)
    {
        // If the tag got is not inside the array with all the tags allowed to be added.
        if (!in_array($tag_got, $tags_allowed))
            // Remove the tag.
            unset($tags_got_exploded[$key]);
    }

    // Join tag got elements (cleaned and checked).
    $tags_got = implode(', ', $tags_got_exploded);

    wp_set_post_tags($post->ID, $tags_got);
}
```

p.s. You should check the set of `$_POST` variables through the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

```
if (isset($_POST['post_get_tags']))
```

Comment: I could not find such a hook as: get_the_tags_allowed
But even if I remove allowed
it gives me an error:
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87

Comment: I also tried to create my own logic, but it works crookedly
http://static2.keep4u.ru/2018/11/20/UKERRR19f906a2550e1027.jpg

Comment: Check the code comments. I wrote you a possible algorithm to manage what you asked for. Since I don't know the structure of your script and database, instead of `get_the_tags_allowed()` you have to make a query or use a built-in function that return all the tags allowed to be added in an array.

Comment: that's exactly what I did
instead of `get_the_tags_allowed()` wrote `get_the_tags()`
and now I have a mistake Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87 Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87 Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-content\themes\pog\content_singl_post_ise.php on line 87

Comment: 87: `if (!in_array($tag_got, $tags_allowed))`

Comment: when trying to enter instead of `get_the_tags_allowed()`,
`get_tags()` the result is the complete removal of all tags.

Comment: Most of all, I don’t understand this part of the   `foreach ($tags_got_exploded as $key => & $tag_got){
        if (!in_array($tag_got, $tags_allowed))   
            unset($tags_got_exploded[$key]);
  }`
After all in_array  compares 2 values, but since $ tag_got = none, then unset  works on all tags without exception

Comment: `get_tags()` return a multidimensional array, so you need to make a small change in order to retrieve just tag names allowed (check edited post, I used array_column to do this)